# Storing values in HI and LO registers of MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers, spim

I am writing certain code in MIPS and I've come to the point where the requirement is to store the result, temporarily, in `HI` and `LO` special registers (both are 4 bytes wide). These instructions are at my disposal:

```
divu     s,t    lo <-- s div t ; hi <-- s mod t
multu    s,t    hi / lo < -- s * t ;
```

So, `divu` stores result of division in `LO` and remainder in `HI`, while `multu` stores result of multiplication in `LO` (lower 4 bytes) and `HI` (higher 4 bytes).

Later, to retrieve result from `HI` and `LO` registers, I can:

```
mfhi $v0
mflo $v1
```

I already figured out how to store result of a calculation in `LO`:

```
ori     $v0,$0,1            # Store result from $a0 into LO
divu    $a0,$v0
```

- the `divu` stores result of the division in LO, so I just divide result by 1 to get it there.

However, storing in `HI` is more complicated. One way would be to force `multu` instruction to shift the value by 32 bits (4 bytes):

```
multu    $a0,0x80000000     # Shift $a0 by 32 bits and store into HI/LO
```

But, the result is that the value in `HI` is 1 bit right of where it should be (so if my value is `0100 1000` then `HI` will contain `0010 0100`).

Does anyone know how to store something in `HI` register?

Comment: *32 bits (8 bytes)*.  uh, 32b is 4 bytes, not 8.  on 32-bit MIPS, HI and LO are each 4 bytes.  It's the 64-bit concatenation of the pair that's 8 bytes (which doesn't fit in any single register).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to extend Nils Pipenbrinck answer:

From MIPS32 arquitechture for programmers

## mthi

Format:                                                     MIPS32 (MIPS I)

```
  MTHI rs
```

Purpose:
To copy a GPR to the special purpose HI register

```
Description: HI ← rs
```

The contents of GPR rs are loaded into special register HI.

Restrictions:

A computed result written to the HI/LO pair by DIV, DIVU,MULT, or MULTU must be read by MFHI or MFLO
before a new result can be written into either HI or LO.
If an MTHI instruction is executed following one of these arithmetic instructions, but before an MFLO or MFHI
instruction, the contents of LO are UNPREDICTABLE. The following example shows this illegal situation:

```
 MUL       r2,r4   # start operation that will eventually write to HI,LO
 ...               # code not containing mfhi or mflo
 MTHI      r6
 ...               # code not containing mflo
                   # this mflo would get an UNPREDICTABLE value
 MFLO      r3
```

Historical Information:

In MIPS I-III, if either of the two preceding instructions is MFHI, the result of that MFHI is UNPREDICTABLE.
Reads of the HI or LO special register must be separated from any subsequent instructions that write to them by two
or more instructions. In MIPS IV and later, including MIPS32 and MIPS64, this restriction does not exist.

## mtlo

Format:         MIPS32 (MIPS I)

```
    MTLO rs
```

Purpose:
To copy a GPR to the special purpose LO register
Description:

```
 LO ← rs
```

The contents of GPR rs are loaded into special register LO.

Restrictions:
A computed result written to the HI/LO pair by DIV, DIVU, MULT, or MULTU must be read by MFHI or MFLO before a new result can be written into either HI or LO.

If an MTLO instruction is executed following one of these arithmetic instructions, but before an MFLO or MFHI instruction, the contents of HI are UNPREDICTABLE.
 The following example shows this illegal situation:

```
 MUL       r2,r4   # start operation that will eventually write to HI,LO
 ...               # code not containing mfhi or mflo
 MTLO      r6
 ...               # code not containing mfhi
                   # this mfhi would get an UNPREDICTABLE value
 MFHI      r3
```

Historical Information:

In MIPS I-III, if either of the two preceding instructions is MFHI, the result of that MFHI is UNPREDICTABLE.
Reads of the HI or LO special register must be separated from any subsequent instructions that write to them by two
or more instructions. In MIPS IV and later, including MIPS32 and MIPS64, this restriction does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

The MIPS instruction-set has a counterpart for MFLO/MFHI.

It's called MTLO/MTHI and does exactly what you want:

```
  mtlo $v0  # moves the contents of v0 into the lo-register
  mthi $v1  # moves the contents of v1 into the hi-register
```

These instructions are rare and often not present in summarized instruction set references.

Btw: Be sure to check the processor manual about the latencies and hazards involved with the LO/HI regs. They are very special and your code may have to things like waiting at least three cycles between a write and a read. Unfortunately this behaviour depends on which CPU you're working on.

Getting this wrong is a common pitfall for aspiring MIPS programmers :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed something I overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what other extreme values might produce interesting results when used as the second argument to multu/divu (I'm being intentionally vague because this looks like a homework question).

Comment: Don't think using multu and divu is possible to store values in HI/LO registers, since each instruction completely overwrites both registers unless great care is taken :( Damn MIPS.