# MIPS Assembly Multiplication and Moving the Hi and Lo into Register

Tags: assembly, mips

`mult` instruction can multiply two 32-bit integers which could give a 64-bit result. The higher significant 32 bits of the result (32 - 63) are saved in Hi and the lower bits (0 - 31) are saved in Lo. After the multiplication I can use `mfhi` and `mflo` to move the result to registers. But it is obviously not possible to write the 64-bit number into a 32-bit register. How can I store the result back into registers and use it? Should I save each part in a separate register and concatenate them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing values in HI and LO registers of MIPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823896/storing-values-in-hi-and-lo-registers-of-mips)

Comment: @BrettHale The link you posted is about moving data from registers to Hi or Lo. My question is the opposite. In fact I want to know how to store a 64-bit number from HI and Lo in 32-bit long registers and manipulate it.

Comment: Well obviously you can't. You have to deal with the product as 64 bits. If the high word is zero the low word can be used as 32 bits.

Comment: And if Hi is not zero?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you save by both `mfhi` and `mflo` to registers separately. You just have to check if your product takes both registers (when Hi is NOT zero) then you take that into account and process both.

Comment: That's exactly my question. How can I process them as the product is 64 bits long and the registers are 32 bits?

Comment: Nohow but separate processing, what's wrong with that? What would you like to do with a result?

Comment: My question is if I have to keep track of High and low parts of the number or if MIPS has a mechanism to do it? Let's say that I want to divide the result by a number. Should I run the division on high and low significant parts separately and then add the result of each after I have moved them to two separate registers or MIPS knows that these are parts of one number?

Comment: Or for example if I want to print the product out, should I print the high significant part first and then concatenate it with the lower part or the MIPS takes care of that and prints both parts in the right order because it's aware that these are parts of one number?

Comment: no it seems to me it knows nothing about they are parts of one number. According to the documentation on MIPS the registers Hi and Lo are not accessible by any means but the commands above, so since they are copied to the general registers they are just regular numbers.